# License getting activated after activation period

Tags: license4j

License getting activated after activation period

I have created the license (let say on 1 Jan 2020) with Validity Period **30 days**, and activation period is **2 days**.
And Not Selected the "Set Activated License Text Generation Time To Activation Time" so my license will expire on 30 Jan 2020.

But when I try to activate the license (let say on 10 Jan 2020) after validity period expired (which is given 2 days and expired on 3 Jan 2020) **still license getting activated**.

I am using below API of license4j which return Activation Status : **Activation Completed**

```
LicenseValidator.autoActivateWithCustomHardwareID(license, customHardwareIDforActivation)
```

Is I am missing something ?? or Activation period is not for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activation period is just for informational use; it does not prohibit activating the license. It is to force the customer to activate the license. e.g. Microsoft use similar licensing method. When you buy a windows or office, you can install and use it for about 1 month, but after 1 month you must activate the license to continue using the software.

So in your software, after validating the license, you should check the activation period, if it is not over, just allow running the software. If it is over, display an activation window to activate the license. If customer does not activate, do not allow to run the software.

After purchasing the license, customer may want to try it on some computer for some time, after some time, he/she may want to install the license on a permanent computer. So it is good to let them to install and use the software without activating for a limited time.